# How to delete multiple rows from a datagridview by selecting the checkboxes in C#?

Tags: c#, button, checkbox, datagridview, delete-row

I have **datagridview** and header checkbox to check all the check boxes in the rows in the checkbox column (index of the column for all the check boxes 0).
I have following code in the deleted button event:

```
for (int i = 0; i < datagridview.Rows.Count; i++) {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) == true) {
                datagridview.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
```

The **datagridview.rows.count** keeps decreasing as the row deleted but I in the loop keeps increasing. Thus, instead of deleting all the checked rows, it deletes some of them only. It does not delete the one with rows index 0, 1, 2 and so on with the new data in the datagridview as I increase in the code.

Comment: Because when you removeat(i) it's 0 on the first iteration and the row below it moves up to index 0 but i is now at 1. Remove them in reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that by keep increasing the index on deletion, you skip the next item in the list:

```
0: [X] Item 0
1: [X] Item 1
2: [X] Item 2
```

> on iteration 0 ... we delete `Item 0` on index 0 OK

```
0: [X] Item 1
1: [X] Item 2
```

> on iteration 1 ... we delete `Item 2` on index 1 BUT we skipped `Item 1` which is now on index 0

Therefore, you should iterate the list in the reverse order, that way when you remove an item, the <del>next</del> previous item's index is still the same:

```
for (int i = datagridview.Rows.Count; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    // ....
}
```

Comment: I think you meant "which is now on index 0"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue after getting hints from Charles as below. Thank you!

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dgvBaleDisposition.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(dgvBaleDisposition.Rows[i]
                                      .Cells[0].Value) == true)
                {
                    dgvBaleDisposition.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                }

                i = i - 1;
                j = j + 1;

                if (j == countRows)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
```